# I need four specific time messages to be generated using moment.js

Tags: typescript, angular6, momentjs

I have a function that I want to use to return a state of an eSignature. This will occur whenever a user eSigns a form.

So I wrote the following functions:

```
setTimeDiffStatement(time: number): string {
  const timeMsgArray = new Array(4);

  // Within the hour, return 
  timeMsgArray[0] = ' 15 minutes ago';
  // Within the date, return 
  timeMsgArray[1] = ' at 2:35 pm';
  // Within the week return
  timeMsgArray[2] = ' on Monday';
  // Outside the week return 
  timeMsgArray[3] = ' on ' + this.theDate.getMonth() + this.theDate.getDay() + this.getOrdinalNum(this.theDate.getDay()) + ' ' + this.theDate.getFullYear();

  const timeMsg = '';

  return '';

}
```

and here's the code for getOrdinalNum

```
getOrdinalNum(n: number): string {
  return n + (n > 0 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10] : '');
}
```

When I call the first function, I need to return one of the timeArrayMessages based on the moment in time we are at using Moment.js

So, using this function, I get the day name and I'd like to pass into the first function above, the time and build it like this function below:

```
getDayName(daynbr: number): string {

  const weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = 'Sunday';
  weekday[1] = 'Monday';
  weekday[2] = 'Tuesday';
  weekday[3] = 'Wednesday';
  weekday[4] = 'Thursday';
  weekday[5] = 'Friday';
  weekday[6] = 'Saturday';

  const n = weekday[daynbr];
  return n;
}
```

Please let me know an easy way to achieve these business rules:

When a form is eSigned then in pseudo code

```
Within the hour, return "15 minutes ago"
Within the date, return "at 2:35 pm"
Within the week return "on Monday"
Outside the week return "on July 10th"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what the `time` argument you are passing into `setTimeDiffStatement` looks like from your description, but for my answer I'll assume you're using a [unix (epoch) timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

You actually don't even need to use your `getDayName` and `getOrdinalNum` methods because the `momentjs` library handles this all for you.

My proposed solution calculates the time difference between now and when the eSignature time was, and then works out the output based on that difference. I've used seconds as the basis to calculate this but you may change this depending on what precision you need. I have also referred to the official documentation below in comments that may help you in your understanding of the library.

```
setTimeDiffStatement(time: number): string {
    const eSignatureSignedTime = time  //assuming this is a unix (epoch) timestamp with milliseconds, eg. 1563868827000
    const currentTime = moment().local();
    const timeDifference = currentTime.diff(moment(eSignatureSignedTime), "seconds");

    //Number of seconds after one week:
    const AFTER_ONE_WEEK = 604801;

    //Number of seconds between one day & one week:
    const BEFORE_ONE_WEEK = 604800;
    const AFTER_ONE_DAY = 86401;

    //Number of seconds between one hour & one week:
    const BEFORE_ONE_DAY = 86400;
    const AFTER_ONE_HOUR = 3601;

    //Number of seconds between the starting time & one hour:
    const BEFORE_ONE_HOUR = 3560;
    const STARTING_TIME = 0;

    if (timeDifference >= STARTING_TIME && timeDifference < BEFORE_ONE_HOUR) {
        return moment(eSignatureSignedTime).fromNow();
        //Outputs "15 minutes ago"
        //Documentation: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

    } else if (timeDifference >= AFTER_ONE_HOUR && timeDifference < BEFORE_ONE_DAY) {
        return "at " + moment(eSignatureSignedTime).format("LT");
        //Outputs "at 2:35 PM"
        //Documentation: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

    } else if (timeDifference >= AFTER_ONE_DAY && timeDifference < BEFORE_ONE_WEEK) {
        return "on " + moment(eSignatureSignedTime).format("dddd");
        //Outputs "on Monday"
        //Documentation: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

    } else if (timeDifference >= AFTER_ONE_WEEK) {
        return "on " + moment(eSignatureSignedTime).format("MMMM Mo");
        //Outputs "on July 10th"
        //Documentation: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

    } else {
        return "Invalid date/time";
    }    
}
```

Comment: Caladeve, thanks. Been hot and heavy on a demo. Will implement today and give feedback.

Comment: @PeterTheAngularDude let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Caladeve, thank you, I will. Going on a vacation until the 6th. I'll let you know then. Forgive the delay.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!